# Fix the ctors so that they pass bottom and top to the superclass ctor

Tags: java

the instruction is the following:

create A    public  method  called  add(Cloud   c)  that    takes   a   cloud   and adds    it  to  the arraylist.The return type of this method should be  boolean, and the method should  always  return  true.

Here is what i have so far:

```
package weather;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sky {
    private ArrayList<Cloud> clouds;

    public Sky(){
        clouds = new ArrayList<Cloud>(100);
    }
```

i have the constructor finished but i dont know how to do the add method..

Comment: What does your question title have to do with the question?

Comment: i was going to ask the different question, but i figured out later on as i went through my code, and some new issue occurred after that, so i changed the summary but i forgot to change the title. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you can add to an array list by using `.add(value)`.  You also don't need to give the value 100 in `clouds = new ArrayList<Cloud>(100);`

So in your case,

```
package weather;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sky {
    private ArrayList<Cloud> clouds;

    public Sky(){
        clouds = new ArrayList<Cloud>();
    }

    public boolean add(Cloud c){
        clouds.add(c);
        return true;  //always return true
    }
}
```